# Do high resolution PhotoOverlays in GoogleEarth need to be Image Pyramids?

Tags: kml, google-earth, gdal

I have a series of ~300 high resolution images (~0.5 gigapixel) which I want embedded as PhotoOverlays in Google Earth. I have them in either of two formats, ~250mb geotiff's (georeferenced & warped) and ~100mb jpg's (which I can localize in GE with explicit coordinates). These images are of very small areas (~100m^2). Ultimately, I will want to share the images online.

Are the file sizes big enough to need Image Pyramids?

If so, is gdal_retile an appropriate tool to produce the pyramids and the KML?